# DefaultPasswordHasher generating different hash for the same value

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a password stored at `database` hashed with `DefaultPasswordHasher` at `add` action.

I have another action for change the password for the loggedin user, on this form I have a field called `current_password` that I need compare with the current password value from `database`.

The issue is that `DefaultPasswordHasher` is generating a different hash for each time that I'm hashing the value of the form so this will never match with the hash from database.

Follow the validation code of the 'current_password' field:

```
    ->add('current_password', 'custom', [
        'rule' => function($value, $context){
            $user = $this->get($context['data']['id']);
            if ($user) {
                echo $user->password; // Current password value hashed from database
                echo '<br>';
                echo $value; //foo
                echo '<br>';
                echo (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($value); // Here is displaying a different hash each time that I post the form

                // Here will never match =[
                if ($user->password == (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($value)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        },
        'message' => 'Você não confirmou a sua senha atual corretamente'
    ])
```

Comment: This is probably "salt"; it's a good thing, because it means you can't look in the database and find all the people whose password is "password". You need to verify the password against the hash with the appropriate function, not compare the old hash with the new.

Comment: As @IMSoP said, see **http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Auth.DefaultPasswordHasher.html#_check**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is the way bcrypt works. Bcrypt is a stronger password hashing algorithm that will generate different hashes for the same value depending on the current system entropy, but that is able to compare if the original string can be hashed to an already hashed password.

To solve your problem use the `check()` function instead of the `hash()` function:

```
 ->add('current_password', 'custom', [
        'rule' => function($value, $context){
            $user = $this->get($context['data']['id']);
            if ($user) {
                if ((new DefaultPasswordHasher)->check($value, $user->password)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        },
        'message' => 'Você não confirmou a sua senha atual corretamente'
```

Comment: Not sure this is specific to bcrypt - any hash can be stored with a salt which will be different if you regenerate it. But the explanation and solution are otherwise correct.

Comment: you are right @IMSoP, the password_hash() function just generates a different salt every time, so that means a different hash.