# How to check current password in cakephp 3.x from model?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How to check current password is correct from cakephp model. I've searched a lot but not found any details information.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780552/cakephp-3-0-compare-database-password-with-the-old-password-while-changing-pas) worked for me.  Just don't forget to add the `use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;` at the top of your UsersTabel model.

Answer (score 0):

I found something very useful for checking the current password on http://base-syst.com/password-validation-when-changing-password-in-cakephp-3/ .

Insert this in your template(change_password.ctp):

```
<div class="users form large-9 medium-9 columns">
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <?= $this->Form->input('current_password', ['type' => 'password', 'label'=>'Current Password', 'value' => ''])?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password', ['type'=>'password' ,'label'=>'Password', 'value' => '']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('confirm_password', ['type' => 'password' , 'label'=>'Repeat password', 'value' => ''])?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Save')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Insert this in your (Users)Table, for validation:

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator )
    {

        $validator
            ->add('current_password','custom',[
                'rule'=>  function($value, $context){
                    $user = $this->get($context['data']['id']);
                    if ($user) {
                        if ((new DefaultPasswordHasher)->check($value, $user->password)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                },
                'message'=>'The old password does not match the current password!',
            ])
            ->notEmpty('current_password');

        $validator
            ->add('password', [
                'length' => [
                    'rule' => ['minLength', 6],
                    'message' => 'The password have to be at least 6 characters!',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('password',[
                'match'=>[
                    'rule'=> ['compareWith','confirm_password'],
                    'message'=>'The passwords does not match!',
                ]
            ])
            ->notEmpty('password');

        $validator
            ->add('confirm_password', [
                'length' => [
                    'rule' => ['minLength', 6],
                    'message' => 'The password have to be at least 6 characters!',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('confirm_password',[
                'match'=>[
                    'rule'=> ['compareWith','password'],
                    'message'=>'The passwords does not match!',
                ]
            ])
            ->notEmpty('confirm_password');

        return $validator;
    }
```

Insert this in your (Users)Controller:

```
public function change_password() {
    $user = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```