# Cakephp 3 : Current password match in controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to match current password before if change. For that I have taken Auth password and then I matched it with current password. But it's returning always false.

Here is the controller code that I have tried

```
 if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
      $obj = new DefaultPasswordHasher;
      $postpassword = $obj->hash($this->request->data['current_password']);
      if($this->Auth->user('password') == $postpassword)
      {
         // code to save change password.                          
      }
      else
      $this->Flash->error(__('The password you have entered does not match !'));

  }
```

Here $postpassword hash working fine, but `$this->Auth->user('password')`  return value 1. How can I get auth password and match with $postpassword ?

Edit

I have get some knowledge then I have solve this problem like this way

```
$password     = '$2y$10$pHbHu6xhNAw/v5HuQ1DSjOm5MPkqZukD1.532ACu7YLgD1ef9K7i2';
       if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $obj = new DefaultPasswordHasher;

            $postpassword = $obj->check($this->request->data['current_password'], $password);
            if($postpassword==1)
            $this -> set('password',"hello");
       }
```

Now I need just `$this->Auth->user('password');` in controller. 
Is it possible in cakephp auth component ?

Comment: I would recommend not putting that much logic in the controller layer ;)
Look at [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/) and how a simple behavior on top of your model can make this a simple one-liner. DRY and clean. You can now just call save() and the rest will be done with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authentication adapter removes the password before returning the data for the identified user, however you should receive `null`, not `1`.

Anyways, if you need that information, you'll have to read it manually, like for example

```
$Table->get($this->Auth->user('id'))->password
```

However, as already [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263383/cakephp-3-current-password-match-in-controller#comment52412835_32263383), this is stuff that is better being done using validation or application rules.

See for example **[DefaultPasswordHasher generating different hash for the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499287/defaultpasswordhasher-generating-different-hash-for-the-same-value)**

Answer (score 4):

Its pretty easy this way:

Insert this in your `(Users)Table` :

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
```

Extend your `function validationDefault(Validator $validator )` like the following:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator ) {

    $validator
        ->add('current_password','custom',[
            'rule'=>  function($value, $context){
                $user = $this->get($context['data']['id']);
                if ($user) {
                    if ((new DefaultPasswordHasher)->check($value, $user->password)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            },
            'message'=>'The old password does not match the current password!',
        ])
        ->notEmpty('current_password');

 return $validator;
}
```

And thats it! :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to hash password,Auth will perform all.

```
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
      $obj = new DefaultPasswordHasher;

      if($this->Auth->user('password') == $this->request->data['current_password'])
      {
         // code to save change password.                          
      }
      else
      $this->Flash->error(__('The password you have entered does not match !'));

  }
```

Comment: $this->Auth->user('password') is return 1. I have tried this code before make hash it also not working.

Comment: use this method in query For example

Comment: $this->User->find('first',
 array('conditions' => 
array( 'User.password' => $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password'])));

Comment: Not actually, may you edit your ans please with details ?

Comment: Fire a find query in condition compare your password field with $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password'])

Comment: @BagwalaIrfan There is no `AuthComponent::password()` method in 3.x anymore, instead the Hasher classes should be used, for generating as well as for comparing passwords.